# does a webworker close itself after its code finishes?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

if I let a webworker run a function. will it close itself after the function is finished?

```js
(function(){a = 3+2;})();
```

or I will need to explicitly close this webworker by calling webworker's close() function?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call `close()` or `terminate()` on web workers. Web workers automatically clean themselves up when they fall out of scope like most JavaScript objects. So in your example, if your web worker looked like this:

```
onmessage = function(e) {
    postMessage(3 + 2);
}
```

And you called it from your main script like this:

```
function doAThing() {
    var myWorker = new Worker('worker.js');
    myWorker.postMessage();
    myWorker.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('Message received from worker', e.data);
    };
}
```

The worker would cease execution after it posted back the result of `3 + 2`, but would still be in memory and could still be called until the myWorker variable fell out of scope.

In this example case you'd no longer be able to call the worker after `doAThing()` completed, and the garbage collector should clean up the worker after `doAThing()` completes and the message callback gets called, since at that point nothing will have a reference anymore.

The case where you'd want to call `close()` or `terminate()` is if you have a long living task you want to end early (say you want to end an XHR request early, or if a user hits a "Cancel" button).